# How to use np-repeat directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am following some tutorials on AngularJS, but the below code is not working for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="simpleApp">
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="entry in collection"> {{ entry }} </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and below is my index.js code

```
var app = angular.module("simpleApp", []);

app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.collection = ['first','second','third'];
    };
})
```

According to the tutorials output must be

- first
- second
- third

but my output is

- {{ entry }}

Comment: Looks like you have a random **};** in your code

Comment: Try `<span ng-bind="entry"></span>` instead of `{{entry}}`.

Comment: I'm thinking that the javascript console would be very helpful for you to determine errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a random **};** in your code

```
app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.collection = ['first','second','third'];
  };
})
```

Should be:

```
app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.collection = ['first','second','third'];
})
```